# How to measure a CPU overheating process when in Idle Mode?

Tags: power, process, logging

Every time my PC is idle for an hour, I return to find the fan at maximum speed and the CPU at 51-52 degrees. It's Windows 7 on an 8150 octocore from AMD. The task manager shows that two of the cores were at 70% usage and the rest are at about 5%, until the moment where i press a keyboard button, where the processes go all back to 5% and the processor cools down.

To find the culprit process, i need to make a graph of the most active processes of the PC, which i can consult when i return. Do you know a program which can help me?

Comment: The easiest would be to open the Task Manager's task list sorted by CPU consumption, disable screen saver and display darkening, and look at the result after an hour. Which, by the way, might eliminate the cause of the behaviour right away... BTW, 50 deg C has nothing to do with "overheating", and the fan may just be poor (like many of the AMB boxed fans).

Comment: If you boot to safe mode does this behavior exhibit itself?

Comment: I use my PC too intensively, i have to get into safe mode and leave the pc running on idle for some time and return. I caught it running at 56 degrees with full fans, and i clicked on the taskmon and it was 93% idle... As soon as i checked the temps the fan and temp went down again. It may be an error with the AMD cool n quiet program, and the processor dynamic clock and voltage changes, i am also checking processes with DaaBoss's suggestoins and "process history" freeware: http://processhistory.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **PROCESS EXPLORER** from Microsoft's [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to give you total CPU time.  Even without touching the keyboard, you should be able to see exactly what processes are consuming all your resources, as well as disk and network performance.  Like almost all Sysinternals tools, you simply run, and don't install Process Explorer.

Right click on the columns shown to "select columns".  From the "Process Performance" tab, check to add at least "CPU Time", (and, I always add CPU Usage, Start Time, and Context Switches, among other additional columns).

Become proficient with Process Explorer, Process Monitor, and other Sysinternals tools and you can diagnose or fix almost anything in your PC.  Microsoft bought Sysinternals, since these tools are used to create and support Windows itself.  There are a number of videos and excellent books available as well to help diagnose any problem.

**TIPS:**

**Admin vs Normal User**
You can't get disk or network stats when running as a normal user, nor can you stop a process you don't own.  So either start in, "run as admin", create a permanent shortcut that is designated to always run as admin, (hit the advanced button in shortcut properties", or restart the program from File: tab as admin.

**Navigate directly to the registry or folder for that process**
Hovering over many of the column entries allows you to see the complete strings without opening properties by hitting enter.  Properties allows you to click on the autostart registry or file location, which opens Explorer or RegEdit to that location.

**Catch temporary fleeting processes**
Some processes come and go, so you can't always catch them.  Slow down the update speed, and watch for the new red entries, which are newly created processes.  Then hit the space bar, which freezes the updates, and then you can open your possibly offending process.

**Speed up your system properly**
For processes that continue to run, you can start Process Explorer days after restarting your PC, and the CPU time will show the accumulated CPU and other usage.  This is handy for finding offending apps that consume tons of network, disk, or CPU usage that you are likely unaware of, that slow you down.  Usually, the worst offenders are your antivirus or anti-malware protections.

Comment: I *think* process explorer needs to be "run as admin" if you want it to see all processes (it is not always run as admin like resmon)

Answer (score 0):

[Process history](http://processhistory.sourceforge.net) is also an easy way to monitor tasks. It's a one click program which logs the start time and end time of all processes on windows. ProcessExplorer is also essential for knowing accurate information about processes.

I used it to find out that the only task was taskeng.exe, the windows task scheduler, running in idle mode until i clicked on return,. some windows tasks use high CPU, for example winupdate: trustedinstaller.exe is running at the moment, doing nothing and waiting for a reboot, using 100% of a core and the 8 cores are running at overdrive speeds with fast fan and high temps.